# event.preventdefault() issues - Trying to stop an anchor tag from loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm setting up a dynamic and responsive video gallery, where you click on a thumbnail and it loads the accompanying video in the larger `<div>` above it. The problem I'm running into is that the `event.preventdefault()` apparently isn't working, because it still links to YouTube rather than loading it. Any help is appreciated.

HTML

```
        <div class="mainvideo">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAQ9-sl13zg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <div id="mainvideowords">
                <h2>#</h2>
                <h3>#</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="videogallery">

            <div class="littlevideo">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HsuzKk6udK8" class="video1"><img src="assets/placeholder.png"></a>
                <div class="littlevideowords">
                    <h4>#</h4>
                    <p>#</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
$(".video1, .video2, .video3").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".mainvideo iframe").prop("src", $(event.currentTarget).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: I had issues with event.preventDefault() in Firefox before...is it browser specific?

Comment: if you aren't actually linking to the video, but just loading it in an iframe, why not just use a div with a data- attribute, instead of an a tag?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, so I don't think so, unless it's broken in BOTH haha.

Comment: @Cruiser Like this: `<div data-link="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HsuzKk6udK8" class="video1"><img src="assets/placeholder.png"></div>` ?

Comment: yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not an answer as to why the event.preventDefault() isn't working, here's how I would approach this. I would adjust the html to look like this:

```
<div class="mainvideo">
   <iframe id="playVideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAQ9-sl13zg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
 // notice ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        <div id="mainvideowords">
       // rest of your code

<div id="videogallery">
    <div class="littlevideo">
        <div data-link="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HsuzKk6udK8" class="video1">
       // notice ^^^^^   
    <img src="assets/placeholder.png"></div>
```

Then your jquery would look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('div[class^="video"]').click(function(){
        var src = $(this).data('link');
        $('#playVideo').prop('src', link);
    });
});
```

The selector at the beginning selects any div whose class begins with 'video', so you don't have to repeat video1, video2, etc. Then, we've added a custom html5 data attribute to our clicked div that we access with the .data('src') line. See docs here: http://api.jquery.com/data/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes.

Finally, by adding an id to our iframe we can select it directly and change the src of the video.

Here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/1sLdkyr2/1/

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm having some trouble with it just not doing anything now... not sure what the matter is.

Comment: when you say it's not doing anything, are you expecting it to auto play the video? or you've looked and the jquery isn't changing the src of the iframe?

Comment: The video at the moment - both the video and the image in fact - are unclickable it seems. Nothing happens when clicked.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle that illustrates your project?

Comment: Ok, I took a look and cleaned it up for you. it's working now. You had a little issue with divs being closed in the wrong spot and using the data-link name instead of the variable link. I included the working fiddle link in my answer. you'll note I added a picture of black lively and a tiny bit of css to illustrate the page. feel free to remove :) also if this did help, please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: I am literally the happiest girl at the ball. WOOOO HOOOOO!!! Thank you thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121253/discussion-between-cruiser-and-b-johnson).